# Socket Webserver

Tags: python, sockets

I try to build a simple web server using Python. 
I try to send a minimum response to mozilla web browser as a client. But, the client browser keep spinning. Code is below:

```
import socket
mysocket = socket.socket(2,1)
mysocket.bind(('',80))
mysocket.listen(5)


cli2,addr2 = mysocket.accept()
print('Client connected')
status = b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
connection_type=b'Connection: close\r\n'
content_type = b'Content-Type: text/html\r\n'  
server = b'Server: Python-Server/5.2\r\n\r\n'
f = open('c:/users/totz/documents/index.html','r')
data = f.read()
data_b = data.encode()
content_html_length_calculation = len(data) * 8
content_length_header = 'Content-Length: ' + str(content_html_length_calculation) + '\r\n'
content_length_header_b = content_length_header.encode()
sending_data = status + connection_type + content_length_header_b + content_type + server
cli2.send(sending_data)
print('Data sent')
mysocket.close()
```

Why the client keep spinning, even Wireshark has told me that this web server has sent this response correctly to the client?

Answer (score 0):

```
content_html_length_calculation = len(data) * 8
```

It looks like that you assume that the content-length is given in bits since you multiple the length of the data with 8. Only, the content-length is given in bytes. Since your claimed content-length is far bigger than the actual data the browser is still waiting for more data.
Apart from that your server does not read the request from the client which might cause additional problems (like reports about "Connection reset" if you close the client socket `cli`).